ODBC driver on Azure app service for ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I have deployed an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API hosted on Azure web app service (Windows). It connects to IBM's DB2 i series database and gets the data. I am using ODBC connection, the drivers are setup correctly on my locale and everything works fine.
When I deploy this to the app service I am getting:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified at
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,...].

How do you install/configure ODBC drivers on azure app service? Thank you!
The express route to the DB2 server from my app service is already created and I can ping it and get response.

Is there a reason you're using ODBC instead of IBM's Data Server Provider library?

Db2® .NET provider can be used to deploy .NET and .NET Core applications on cloud environments using the NuGet packages.

We can use the Db2 .NET provider for Core to deploy .NET Core applications to connect to IBM® database servers. These applications can run on Windows and Linux. The following NuGet package are available for download.
For Windows: IBM.Data.DB2.Core
For Linux: IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx


Likely because To connect to Db2 for z/OS® and IBM Db2 for IBM i servers, you require the Db2 Connect Server license. which is not cheap.

@jason The pre-requisite for this nuget package to run is to install the Db2 v11.1 IBM Data Server Driver Package and add entries to the driver configuration file on local. Where do I download this executable from?
